# Checking if username and password is correct

Tags: java, android, sql, sharedpreferences

I am working on an app where you have to sign in with the username and the password.  I've done as much as getting the user to enter their information in the preferences, but i am not sure how to implement the test in the 2 text fields that i have in my main xml.

How would i go about retreiving the data from preferences andchecking if the user's sign in information is correct?

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Sign up for Ebenezer&apos;s Notepad" >
</PreferenceCategory>

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="usernamePref"
    android:title="Create a Login Username" >
</EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="passwordPref"
                android:title="Create a Login Password" >
</EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="reEnterPref"
    android:title="Please Re-Enter Password" >
</EditTextPreference>
```

This is my preferences.xml

an update to my code

```
final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        ImageView Notepad = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.notepad);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final String user = sp.getString("usernamePref", null);
        final String pass = sp.getString("passwordPref", null);
        final String users = username.getText().toString();
        final String passw = password.getText().toString();
        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (user == users && pass == passw) {
                    Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Notepad.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen1);
                }
            }
        });
```

The code doesnt give me error but it does not do anything. Help Please.  I am under the impression that all my classes can see my preferences is that correct? because if not then that maens i need to call my preferences to this class.  If anybody can knows please tell me.

Comment: friend see updated answer and if it is right that mark it.

Comment: Learn java before programm on Android http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through Folloting coding u will get **EditTextPreference** Value  after compare it as u want.

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String username = sp.getString("usernamePref",null);  
String password= sp.getString("passwordPref",null);
```

**friend dont use == operator use .equals method like                               `if(user.equals(users) && pass.equals(passw))`

Comment: also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535132/how-do-you-validate-the-format-and-values-of-edittextpreference-entered-in-andro

Answer (score 1):

Do some Googling

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

Get text from preferences and use:
[String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)
[String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)